# Disable autocomplete in Xamarin.Forms PCL XAML Page

Tags: xaml, mvvm, portable-class-library, xamarin.forms

I have a PCL which stores my MVVM pages in XAML. I have the following in the XAML file, but I'd like to disable the autocomplete feature on the keyboard. Does anyone know how I can do this in the XAML?

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Code}" Placeholder="Code" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms supports a [KeyboardFlags.Suggestion](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.KeyboardFlags%2FF) enum which I assume is intended to control this behavior, but it doesn't appear to be very well documented.

Comment: @benpage The documentation doesn't appear to have been updated, but there is a `None` member now. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/c1cf72080abbbc06571e5a64ef8777c35f7014f0/Xamarin.Forms.Core/KeyboardFlags.cs#L8

Answer (score 33):

Custom `Keyboard` instances can be created in XAML using the `x:FactoryMethod` attribute. What you're wanting can be achieved with the following markup:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Code}" Placeholder="Code">
  <Entry.Keyboard>
    <Keyboard x:FactoryMethod="Create">
      <x:Arguments>
        <KeyboardFlags>None</KeyboardFlags>
      </x:Arguments>
    </Keyboard>
  </Entry.Keyboard>
</Entry>
```

`KeyboardFlags.None` removes all special keyboard features from the field.

[Multiple enums](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/KeyboardFlags.cs) can be specified in XAML by separating them with a comma:

```
<KeyboardFlags>CapitalizeSentence,Spellcheck</KeyboardFlags>
```

When you don't need a custom `Keyboard`, you can use [one of the predefined ones](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/choose-keyboard-for-entry/) by taking advantage of the `x:Static` attribute:

```
<Entry Placeholder="Phone" Keyboard="{x:Static Keyboard.Telephone}" />
```

Comment: It would be wonderful if this could be incorporated into a style?

Answer (score 2):

While there's already an answer, I thought I'd elaborate a bit further about usage in XAML.

Unlike in code-behind, you cannot create a new instance of the Keyboard class to be used, but there IS a way. Hopefully you're already xaml-ified your App.cs (remove it, and create App.xaml and App.xaml.cs), that way you don't have to check if the Resources property has been initialized yet.

The next step is to override the OnStart() method, and add the proper entries for the various keyboards you use. I usually use three keyboards: numeric, e-mail and text. Another useful one is the Url keyboard, but you can add it the same way.

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    base.OnStart();
    this.Resources.Add("KeyboardEmail", Keyboard.Email);
    this.Resources.Add("KeyboardText", Keyboard.Text);
    this.Resources.Add("KeyboardNumeric", Keyboard.Numeric);
}
```

This little code will make the keyboards available as static resources. To use them in XAML, just do the following:

```
<Entry x:Name="emailEntry" Text="{Binding EMail}" Keyboard="{StaticResource KeyboardEmail}" />
```

And voilá, your entry now has an e-mail keyboard.

Comment: Creating resources for static members is not necessary. See my answer for details on the `x:Static` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The KeyboardFlags should do it, something like:

```
MyEntry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Create(KeyboardFlags.CapitalizeSentence | KeyboardFlags.Spellcheck);
```

Comment: In a way, yes. You will have to programmatically create resources in App.OnStart, and reach them as StaticResource, with binding. I'll add an answer in a moment.

Comment: @Julien See my answer for how to create custom keyboards using XAML only.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I found a way to do this in styles.

I have all of my styles defined in a `ResourceDictionary` in my `App.xaml`. There I can do things like:

```xml
<Style x:Key="StyleEntryNumeric" TargetType="Entry">
    <Setter Property="ClearButtonVisibility" Value="WhileEditing" />
    <Setter Property="Keyboard" Value="Numeric" />
</Style>
```

and then use it like:

```xml
<Entry Style="{DynamicResource StyleEntryNumeric}" />
```

But, what if I want to set `KeyboardFlags`? Well, I did that with a bit of code in my `App.xaml.cs` and a simple binding. First, in the top of my `App.xaml`:

```xml
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        x:Name="ThisControl"
        x:Class="App.Forms.App">
```

Then where my styles are in the same `App.xaml`:

```xml
<Style x:Key="StyleEntryText" TargetType="Entry">
    <Setter Property="ClearButtonVisibility" Value="WhileEditing" />
    <Setter Property="Keyboard" Value="{Binding Source={x:Reference ThisControl}, Path=KeyboardText}" />
</Style>
```

Finally, in my `App.xaml.cs` code behind:

```cs
public Keyboard KeyboardText
    => Keyboard.Create(KeyboardFlags.CapitalizeNone | KeyboardFlags.Spellcheck);
```

And, I can create other similar properties in my code behind to use for other styles if needed.