# Can I prevent keyboard suggestions from Xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use xamarin.forms to develop an Android app and need to prevent completion suggestions on a text field. In vanilla Android I would set the inputtype to type_text_flag_no_suggestions. Can I do this from xamarin.forms using xaml for the layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code building the user interface for a page, add a `Keyboard` property to an `Entry`, and use the `Create` method to specify the `None` constant of the `KeyboardFlags` enumeration. This specifies that no suggested word completions will be offered on text that the user enters.

```
Content = new StackLayout {
    Padding = new Thickness(0,20,0,0),
    Children = {
        new Entry { Keyboard = Keyboard.Create(KeyboardFlags.None) }
    }
};
```

Note:  this flag will also disable your [other flags](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.KeyboardFlags/#Members).

[documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.KeyboardFlags/)  is not updated but this flag is now added check [github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/c1cf72080abbbc06571e5a64ef8777c35f7014f0/Xamarin.Forms.Core/KeyboardFlags.cs#L8).

Additional references:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26978071/3758024
2. https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/choose-keyboard-for-entry/#Specifying_additional_keyboard_options

Comment: Still get text suggestions with this. There is an [open bug report](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3487) for this I think.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to disable Suggestions shown on the Keypad while you input text in an `Entry`. In your XAML code just add property `Keyboard="Email"` in your `Entry`.

So Finally your code will look like

```xml
<Entry Placeholder="Enter the word" Keyboard="Email" />
```

Hope this answers the question.

Comment: Could you please explain why you are suggesting the use of Email type of a keyboard for this case when it's not actually specified it's an email field? How is the behavior of this flag appropriate here?

Comment: @iBobb, The question asked states that the user wants to ***prevent completion suggestions on a text field*** ie `Entry` in Xamarin Forms. Hence When the `Keyboard` property of an `Entry` is set to `Keyboard="Email"` Keyboard suggestions are not displayed. Why don't you try and check.

Comment: I simply wanted to make it clear for any passersby like me that this is a "workaround" of sorts, as semantically email is incorrect here. Mentioning that the `Keyboard` of type `Entry` offers no suggestions, and hence the use, is exactly what makes that clear so thank you for that. To further explain, XF is simply not offering the more fitting `textNoSuggestions` that Android offers, which I think we can agree makes more sense and cant cause any confusions. When I read the documents and SO, I saw someone suggesting to use `Plain`