# DisplayPromptAsync is unable to disallow suggestions in Xamarin on Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, keyboard

I have a working Xamarin Forms app for Android, [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform) and one of these days, iOS.

I ask the user to type a userid in a DisplayPromptAsync() and I would like to disallow suggestions, which in this situation are unhelpful at best and counterproductive at worst. Below is the code. I pass keyboard flags with Suggestions not turned on, but Android still prompts for suggestions. What should I be doing differently?

```
Keyboard kb = Keyboard.Create(KeyboardFlags.CapitalizeCharacter);
string placeholderUser = String.IsNullOrEmpty(workingSystem.Userid) ? "userid" : workingSystem.Userid.Trim();
string defaultUser = String.IsNullOrEmpty(workingSystem.Userid) ? null : workingSystem.Userid.Trim();
string userid = await DisplayPromptAsync("Userid?", question, "OK", promptSkip, placeholderUser, 8, kb, defaultUser);
```

Comment: Does it also happen if you use `Keyboard.Create(KeyboardFlags.None);`? See [open bug](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3487) and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338767/can-i-prevent-keyboard-suggestions-from-xamarin-forms). Worse case, using an "email" keyboard has been suggested as one work-around, that may improve the situation.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, thanks. (1) KeyboardFlags.None is no better, and I lose the upper-casing. (2) I find a lot of hits for <Xamarin Android Disable Suggestions> including the one you suggest, but all are for Entry not DisplayPromptAsync. (3) But the email keyboard does seem to solve the problem. Not entirely sure because I only have one test case and not sure where Android gets its suggestions from, but it seems worst case no worse. I can live with the "@ sign" key layout. Question: is there a way to specify flags with a "named" keyboard like email? I could not figure it out.

Comment: I think its either flags or named, not both at same time.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, that is what Intellisense seems to be telling me.