# Disable iOS autocomplete in Xamarin.Forms SearchBar

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a [Xamarin.Forms SearchBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/searchbar) to search for information on a remote server. This data is displayed in a ListView below the searchbar like the following:

[image: iOS Xamarin.Forms SearchBar with autocomplete/autocorrect]

Pseudocode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage ... >
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <SearchBar 
                x:Name="SearchBar"
                Placeholder="Search for a business..."
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                SearchCommand="{Binding PerformSearch}"
                SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference SearchBar}}">
            </SearchBar>
            <ListView 
                x:Name="SearchResults" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SearchResults}"
                ...
                >
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Is it possible to disable the autocomplete/autocorrect in the keyboard? I know for a [Text.Entry it is possible to set IsTextPredictionEnabled to false](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry#enable-and-disable-text-prediction) but I don't see a way to configure a SearchBar in a similar way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, according to the [SearchBar Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.searchbar?view=xamarin-forms#properties), the Keyboard for the InputView is exposed. Therefore,  similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39378157/2557554), it can be achieved in the XAML by using the `x:FactoryMethod` attribute:

```
<SearchBar 
    x:Name="SearchBar"
    Placeholder="Search for a business..."
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
    SearchCommand="{Binding PerformSearch}"
    SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference SearchBar}}">
    <SearchBar.Keyboard>
        <Keyboard x:FactoryMethod="Create">
            <x:Arguments>
                <KeyboardFlags>None</KeyboardFlags>
            </x:Arguments>
        </Keyboard>
    </SearchBar.Keyboard>
</SearchBar>
```

Comment: You can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).